# Can't send ssl ceriticate between guzzle client and goutte

Tags: php, symfony, guzzle, goutte

i have this code inside a class:

```
use Goutte\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
[...]

  $this->client = new Client();
    $this->guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array(
        'verify' => false,
    ));
    $this->client->setClient($this->guzzleClient);
```

Then I call it making a request on a website like that:

```
  $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url);
```

Its like when I put guzzle inside goutte it ignores guzzle properties because if I call the website without goutte client it works, anyone know why isn't working? thanks

Comment: I have tryed a few things but still not working:

$crawler = $this->client->request('GET', $url . "sklepy", ['verify' => false]);
$this->client->getClient()->setDefaultOption('config/curl/' . CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);